# Why is Net.Socket.Write() not sending the full string to my TCP client?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, winsock, cout

EDIT: Im desperate to get this thing done so I can move onto a new project, heres the source: https://github.com/eanlockwood/TalkmonClient

Everything else works fine. The server is well aware of the usernames associated with the clients and it sends information to them accordingly, but the weird thing is the string cuts off after the first variable. Here is the loop for a typical send message:

```
function SendMessage(msg, client)
{

    const clientName = ClientNames.get(client);
    let recieverMsg = `${clientName}: ${msg}`;

    console.log(recieverMsg);


    Clients.forEach(elm => {
        if(elm != client)
        {
            elm.write(recieverMsg);
        }
        else {
            elm.write("You: " + msg);
        }
    })

}
```

msg is the chunk.toString() in the socket.on('data') event, again, node picks up what this string means, it debugs fine but in the client (imagine the windows cmd) itll just print the username and go to the next line.

The loop for the client side is pretty simple too,

```
char buff[4090];

do
    {
        ZeroMemory(buff, 4090);
        int messageRevieved = recv(sock, buff, 4090, 0);

        if (messageRevieved > 0)
        {
            userInput->FreezeInput();
            cout << buff << endl;
            userInput->UnFreezeInput();
        }

    } while (0 == 0);
```

User input is handled in its own class on a seperate thread, again, working just fine.

I think it has to do with a misunderstanding of what socket.write and recv actually do or maybe I just dont understand javascript strings enough. Either way this problem is annoying because its the last step in creating my app

Ive done some extensive tests too, it really just doesnt like the concat strings. Itll print everything up until the first variable, meaning I could have socket.write("hehehehehehe " + variable1 + " kadjgkdgad"); and it would print hehehehehe [variable1 value] and just stop

**Tl;dr: The server will write to the sockets up to the first variable in a concat'd string and then stop, its so weird.**

EDIT: The dependencies used serverside are Net and dotnet if that makes a difference.

EDIT 2: I found another issue. After sending a few messages the client who sent the messages will stop printing the "you: " part and will only print the message, it will do this server side too but its weird because the receiving clients will still print out who the message is from.

Comment: What is the elm.write call?

Comment: Can you make a demo that I can run and encounter the same issue that is as minimal as possible?

Comment: @paradigm111 Ill do you one better, I made everything open source https://github.com/eanlockwood/TalkmonClient Its a "beginner" project anyways so its not like I got anything to hide. The talkroom folder is the server portion and everything else is the cpp class

Comment: My guess is that your `write` call is succeeding. However, you aren't checking the return value to see how many bytes were actually sent.  The problem is likely on the `recv` side. Are you aware that just because you send N bytes into a TCP socket, that doesn't mean `recv` will return that exact number of bytes?  It could return less (very often) or even more than N bytes (multiple messages).

Comment: Also, your `cout << buff` statement is slightly risky because there's no guarantee your buffer contains a null terminating char.  If I manage to send you exactly 4090 bytes (or more) before your `recv` calls loops on it, you have a char array without the guarantee of a null char.

Comment: @selbie Thank you for the answer! Do you have any suggestions to make the call guarantee the proper amount of bytes were sent? I thought TCP wasnt supposed to send anything until the proper amount of data was transferred

Comment: @Thugsy49 - The main issue your code has is that it assumes that `recv` will always return a full message from a corresponding `send` call. That is an incorrect assumption. You should think of your recv socket as a stream of bytes. An easy approach would be to have a fixed size message header in your send stream that indicates the size of the remaining bytes to read for that message.  You read the 4 byte header to discover the size of the text message, then read exactly that many bytes from the socket before printing out your message.

Comment: Also, you may (and will) only receive partial messages, so you need to handle the case where your message header tells you to expect 100 bytes, but you only get back 75 on the subsequent recv call.  you need to invoke recv again until you get all 100 bytes.  Further, it's even possible your message header becomes fragmented.  Test your code as if `recv` would only return 1 byte back at a time.  You'll conclude fast you need do some buffering, protocol parsing, etc... but will make your code very robust.